# What causes a UML question to be migrated to Programmers?

Tags: discussion, migration

I was just looking through some UML questions and noticed [Get Methods and Class-Relationships in UML-Diagrams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8759471/get-methods-and-class-relationships-in-uml-diagrams?noredirect=1) was migrated to programmers.SE. To me, it doesn't look any different from any other [uml](/questions/tagged/uml) question on Stack Overflow.

Could anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens when five regular users, who still don't understand the difference between the two sites, vote to migrate it to Programmers.

Thanks to [NullUserException อ_อ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/149052/nulluserexception), the question's migration history has been cleared, and [the question reopened on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8759471/get-methods-and-class-relationships-in-uml-diagrams?noredirect=1).

Comment: I've cleared it.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ elephant shoes!

Comment: Thanks @MarkTrapp and Null. Was hoping it wasn't just me not understanding the different between the two.